# Angular Wait For Promise To Result For Variable To Show In Template

Tags: angular, typescript

I am simply trying to pull data from a database and display it using angular tmeplate.

here is my view.ts

```
//Global variable
rec;

  async getStats(stats) {
    this.result = await this.userService.getStats(stats);
  }
```

here is my userService.ts

```
  getStats(stats) {
    console.log(stats);
    const url = "http://localhost:3000/get/stats";
    return this.http.post(url, {stats: stats}).toPromise();
  }
```

here is my view.html:

```
<h1 *ngIf="result">Rec</h1>
```

When the result finally gets a value, the H1 does not appear in the view.

Comment: Well your getStats() method doesn't return anything... So it returns undefined. And undefined is falsy.

Comment: My mistake, I am returning I didn't copy code right. I am receiving the correct values and logging the values in the console correctly, but it is not appearing in my view. Unless I click on something on the page then the value show, but not automatically.

Comment: The code was updated for the return statement

Comment: What is value of result after the promise is satisfied?

Comment: An array of numbers that is the correct result.